# user's mulit profile in wso2 identity server

Tags: wso2-identity-server

Is it possible that a user has multiple profiles and want one of them can be selected during login by user? for example user has a default profile that no age attribute and other profile can be defined with some other attribute same as age and user during login can be select except  user's default profile?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

At the moment WSO2 IS latest release version was IS 5.1.0. IS 5.1.0 have multiple profile feature, but current implementation did not provide you mention scenario. In WSO2 current implementation does not provide the user (multiple profile created) selection during login. WSO2 IS future release can be available this feature.